# Is it possible to multiply numbers without using the multiplication operator?

Tags: number-theory

This is a pointless and otherwise stupid question. But I want to train my brain in logical usage, so I decided to think of a way to solve this. I managed to come up with this equation, but it uses the mathematical operator.

$$f(a,b)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\left(i\div\left(\frac b2\right)\right)-1\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{a}\left(a\div\left(\frac a2\right)\right)-1\right)$$

It doesn't exactly use the operator, however, it uses multiplication in it. Which means my task has failed.

Before anyone says this is useless, please recognize I am indeed trying to train my brain to think mathematically :)

Comment: what part of is that formula mathematical? Most mathematicians would write that in a form $a\sum_{i=1}^b \frac{2i}{b}-1$

Comment: Your text is unclear on two points: 1) "It doesn't exactly use the operator, however, it uses multiplication in it." ??? 2) what do you mean by $i\div(b\div2)$ ??

Comment: What aboout simply $a \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^a b$?

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't know you could do that. @YvesDaoust why are you spamming question marks? It seems kind of rude :). Also, I'm not sure what part of that text was not clear.

Comment: If you can produce an addition operator that takes any number of inputs then you'll be fine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust after re-reading your comment I see what your point is. I'm not using the $$\dot$$ , instead I'm multiplying them via parentheses.

Comment: If your goal is to avoid the dot, why don't you write $ab$ ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ancient Egyptians used to perform multiplies by dichotomy:

- halve $a$ and double $b$ at the same time,
- take the sum of the $b$'s every time $a$ was odd.

Example: $23\times 42$

$$23 / \color{green}{42}\\11 / \color{green}{84}\\5 / \color{green}{168}\\2 / \color{red}{336}\\1 / \color{green}{672} \\\overline{\ \ \ \ \color{green}{966}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your straightforward answer!! I had no idea it was this easy :P

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to express multiplication in terms of division:

$$ a \times b = a \div \left( 1 \div b \right) $$

or, in various more traditional notations,

$$ a \cdot b = ab = \frac{a}{\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{a}{1/b} = a/(1/b)$$

Comment: should that be $ab = \frac{a}{\frac{1}{b}}$?

Comment: Also, once again, thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need addition and a lot of cat herding.

Defining multiplication over the naturals is straightforward:
$$a\cdot b = \sum_{n=1}^{b}a$$

The problem gets a little trickier when both $a$ and $b$ are integers or any higher construct, and the details will depend on your construction. Consider defining integers as pairs of naturals $(\alpha ,~ \beta)$ to encode the idea of subtraction generally being $\alpha - \beta$ (which doesn't exist in the naturals when $\alpha < \beta$, which is why we have to invent integers). After wrangling with equivalence classes where e.g. $(0,~ 3) \sim (1,~ 4)$ you can then define addition as

$$(a,~ b) + (c,~ d) = (a+c,~ b+d),~ \{a,b,c,d\} \in \mathbb{N}$$ And multiplication as

$$(a,~ b) \cdot (c,~ d) = (a\cdot c + b\cdot d,~ a\cdot d + b\cdot c),~ \{a,b,c,d\} \in \mathbb{N}$$ But since we've already shown how to multiply naturals by addition we could dispense with multiplication in the above.

Rationals can now be made by pairs of integers (with even more equivalence class wrangling) and multiplication of rationals is then reduced to multiplication of integers which is multiplication of naturals which is repeated addition. I encourage you to have fun writing this out. Feel free to replace addition with successor functions on the next rainy day.

If you are still not satisfied because you absolutely positively *have* to multiply $\pi$ times $\exp(1)$, the logic actually does follow through with real numbers as well if you use something like equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals to define them.

Let's not discuss exponentiation.

Comment: Thank you aswell, I always think to hard on the most basic things >:(